# Apply access control to sub page with custom domain

Tags: laravel, dns

I have a main website example.com, develop using Laravel. This website also provide a personal page for subscribed users at example.com/user1, example.com/user2, etc.

Currently, I control the access by URL, by verifying the username in the URL if the user is active or not.

However, I'm planning to give the URL its own domain. I have read about using DNS & htaccess, but it has to be done manually for every single user. I'm planning something that can be control programmatically.

Comment: Do you actually want individual subdomains, or just routes that use a domain prefix like `username.acme.test`?

Comment: individual domain e.g happyuser1.com = example.com/user1, user2happy.com = example.com/user2

Comment: You don't need actual subdomains to achieve that, you can use [subdomain routing](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-group-subdomain-routing)

Comment: thanks Unflux, good info. If I want to use actual domain, I can create cname at dns using this method.